# How to implment laps in Stop Watch iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nstimer, stopwatch

I am building one application which has stop watch as its accessory function. I am trying to do something very similar to iOS stop watch. I got stop, reset functionality working but I could not get start (once it stop and user click on start) and lap functions working properly. I tried to look around for this problem  but I could not find anything besides one time start and reset stop watch tutorials.Here is what I have right now. Can anyone help me out here with this functions ?

```
// Stop Watch Code Begins

- (void)updateTimer
{
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
stopWatchLable.text = timeString;
[dateFormatter release];

}

 -(IBAction)startTapped:(id)sender
{
if ([self.start.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"])
{
    NSLog(@"Start Tapped");
    [self.start setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.reset setTitle:@"Lap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.startDate =[NSDate date];
    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];

 }
else if ([self.start.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Stop"])
{
    NSLog(@"Stop Tapped");
    [self.start setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.reset setTitle:@"Reset" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [self updateTimer]; 
}
}
-(IBAction)resetTapped:(id)sender
{   
if ([self.reset.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Reset"])
{
    NSLog(@"Reset Tapped");
    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [stopWatchLable setText:@"00:00:00.000"];
}
else if ([self.reset.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Lap"])
{
    NSLog(@"Lap Tapped");        
}
}
-(IBAction)hideTapped:(id)sender
{
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect endFrame = self.stopWatchView.frame;
endFrame.origin.y = screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height;

// start the slide down animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

// we need to perform some post operations after the animation is complete
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(slideDownDidStop)];

self.stopWatchView.frame = endFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];

// grow the table back again in vertical size to make room for the date picker
CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.frame;
newFrame.size.height += self.stopWatchView.frame.size.height;
self.tableView.frame = newFrame;
//self.tableView.frame = screenRect;

[stopWatchTimer invalidate];
stopWatchTimer = 0;
[stopWatchLable setText:@"00:00:00.000"];
[self updateTimer];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't take this the wrong way, but you have one bad design choice in your code: You should not rely on a button text to tell you what you want to do – if at some point in the future you localize your application you'll have to redo the timer.

That said, here's how I would implement a stopwatch: You need two instance variables, `NSTimer` **timer** and `NSDate` **startDate**. For a lap function you'll need another one, an `NSMutableArray` **laps**. Your two buttons are fine, using simple logic you can decide what you have to do when tapping (untested code!):

#### Start/Stop button

```
if (!timer) {
    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 / 10.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    [self updateTimer];
    // set button text to STOP and LAP
}

// there already is a timer, stopwatch running, so we want to stop
else {
    if ([timer isValid]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    self.timer = nil;
    [self updateTimer];
    // set button text to START and RESET
}
```

#### Reset/Lap button

```
// if we have a timer, we want to take a lap
if (timer) {
    if (!laps) {
        self.laps = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [laps addObject:[NSDate date]];
    [self updateTimer];
}

// there is no timer, so we want to reset
else {
    self.startDate = nil;
    [self updateTimer];

    // delete all laps
    self.laps = nil;
}
```

Now you only have to modify **updateTimer** to do what you want it to do. In updateTimer, you should also check whether **startDate** is nil or not before you calculate anything. For the laps you can just loop over the **laps** array and calculate the difference between **startDate** and the date in the array, or even between the dates in the array.

I hope this helps!