# After resuming timer, timer counts twice as fast

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I'm learning Mac OS X Programming now. My first project was to write a simple stopwatch. I know you could use NSTimer, but I thought I would learn more, if I all the work my own. The App works fine. But after resuming the Stopwatch, it skips every second number..

Here the code:

```
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    started = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Stop pressed: %i", started);
}

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    if(!started){
        started = TRUE;
        [self tock:nil];  
    }
    else {
        started = FALSE; 
    }
}

- (void) tock:(id)sender { 
     if(started == TRUE) {
         seconds++;
     };

     [self performSelector:@selector(tock:) withObject:(self) afterDelay:(1.0)];
     _anzeige.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%i"), seconds];
}
```

Comment: Do you see that behavior when you wait 2seconds between hitting stop and then hitting start again?  It looks like you will still have at least on tock queued up a after hitting stop, which will fire 1second later, causing the step to fire and then starting the process over.   If you click start in less than a second, you will have 2 in the queue and they will each fire and separately respawn.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873627/how-to-implment-laps-in-stop-watch-iphone-app

Comment: I think you're right. It seems like its queueing up...directly after resuming you quickly see flashing the missing number..after some seconds you see every number but the intervall is shorter...how do I need to change the code? Yes I know you can do it differently, but I want to know the flaw with this way..I'm still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Declare following two variables in your .h file

```
NSTimer *secondTimer;
int seconds;
```

Step 2 : Then initialize second to 0 in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    seconds = 0;
}
```

Step 3 : Write following methods and assing IBOutlets for the respective Start and Stop method

```
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    // Check if time is enable stop it first    
    if([secondTimer isValid])
    {
        [secondTimer invalidate];
        secondTimer = nil;
    }
}

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    // Check if time is enable stop it first
    if([secondTimer isValid])
    {
        [secondTimer invalidate];
        secondTimer = nil;
    }

    // now start a new timer
    secondTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(tock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) tock
{
    seconds++;
    NSLog(@"%d",seconds);
    // if you want to display second in UILabel uncomment following line
    //[lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and Use the start time in the NSDate variable lObjstrt and

```
NSTimeInterval lTimeInterval=[lObjCurrentDateStr timeIntervalSinceDate:lObjstrt];
NSDate *lObjTimerDatePtr =[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:lTimeInterval];
NSDateFormatter *lObjDateFormatterPtr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[lObjDateFormatterPtr setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SS"];
[lObjDateFormatterPtr setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
NSString *m_cObjSprintTimePtr=[lObjDateFormatterPtr stringFromDate:lObjTimerDatePtr];
NSString *m_cObjSprintTimerValuePtr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ secs", self.m_cObjSprintTimePtr];
```

With this you can get the timer accordingly and try to rest the timer after stopping like:

```
if((NSTimer *)nil != m_cObjSprintTimerPtr) {
    [m_cObjSprintTimerPtr invalidate];
    m_cObjSprintTimerPtr = (NSTimer *)nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` calls. Otherwise, they'll stack up every time you call `tock:`.

Comment: Per the docs, +[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:]

Answer (score -1):

First of all you usually just start such loop in separate thread and control it with the flag.
Second, if you want to make your stopper to be accurate you must save a time-stamp when you start your timer and each time your timer loops show the difference between start time-stamp and current time-stamp. Example:
    [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

Comment: For what exactly I got -1?